# Proper index on a mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

When I run the following query on a table that has 22M rows it in it takes 20 seconds to run:

```
select p.*,
(select avg(close)
from endOfDayData p2
where p2.symbol = p.symbol and
p2.date between p.date - interval 6 day and p.date
) as MvgAvg_X
from endOfDayData p
where p.symbol = 'AAPL'
```

The table structure looks like:

```
mysql> desc endOfDayData;
+--------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| date   | date          | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| symbol | varchar(14)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| open   | decimal(10,4) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| high   | decimal(10,4) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| low    | decimal(10,4) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| close  | decimal(10,4) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| volume | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

and the following indexes exist:

```
mysql> show index from endOfDayData;
+--------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| endOfDayData |          0 | PRIMARY    |            1 | date        | A         |      162294 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| endOfDayData |          0 | PRIMARY    |            2 | symbol      | A         |    24019617 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| endOfDayData |          1 | EOD_dates  |            1 | date        | A         |       50145 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| endOfDayData |          1 | EOD_symbol |            1 | symbol      | A         |       14322 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The machine is a dedicated box with 80GB of ram and dual processor.  I feel that it should be running in under a second with the correct indexes.  Thanks

```
| id | select_type        | table | type | possible_keys                | key        | key_len | ref                | rows | Extra                 |  
+----+--------------------+-------+------+------------------------------+-------‌​-----+---------+--------------------+------+-----------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | p     | ref  | EOD_symbol                   | EOD_symbol | 16      | const              | 8409 | Using index condition |  
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | p2    | ref  | PRIMARY,EOD_dates,EOD_symbol | EOD_symbol | 16      | financial.p.symbol | 1677 | Using index condition |
```

I have created a new table with ID int as a primary key and created an index on symbol, date.

```
CREATE INDEX EODDateSym ON endOfDayData_new (symbol, date) USING BTREE;
```

and still getting 17 seconds.  Thanks again for all the ideas and help

my my.conf is

```
[mysql]

# CLIENT #
port                           = 3306
socket                         = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld]

# GENERAL #
user                           = mysql
default-storage-engine         = InnoDB
socket                         = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
pid-file                       = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.pid

# MyISAM #
key-buffer-size                = 32M
myisam-recover                 = FORCE,BACKUP

# SAFETY #
max-allowed-packet             = 16M
max-connect-errors             = 1000000

# DATA STORAGE #
datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql/

# BINARY LOGGING #
log-bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
expire-logs-days               = 14
sync-binlog                    = 1
server_id              = 1

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size                 = 32M
max-heap-table-size            = 32M
query-cache-type               = 0
query-cache-size               = 0
max-connections                = 500
thread-cache-size              = 50
open-files-limit               = 65535
table-definition-cache         = 4096
table-open-cache               = 4096

# INNODB #
innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 512M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 1
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 68G

# LOGGING #
log-error                      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-error.log
log-queries-not-using-indexes  = 1
slow-query-log                 = 1
slow-query-log-file            = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log
```

Comment: Can you post the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE endOfDayData` instead of the `DESC` version?

Comment: How many rows are being returned from the subquery? select avg(close)
from endOfDayData p2
where p2.symbol = p.symbol and
p2.date between p.date - interval 6 day and p.date

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to see which indexes are getting used, and which indexes should be created to help this query.

Comment: @user3546638 There's an edit link below to your question. Use that to add this kind of information.

Comment: How many rows in `endOfDayData` have symbol `AAPL`?

Comment: 8400 dependent subqueries is a lot. Since the moving average always just considers records in the past six days, add a column for it and set the value when you create the end of day record. Then, you won't have the sub queries.

Comment: Marcus, that is my ultimate goal which is why I have a few columns SMA5, SMA10, ect.., when I did an update it went out to lunch.  So I started to look at trying to improve the speed.  If 17sec is the best I can get, than so be it.

Comment: Do you work for the Co-op?

Comment: Try increasing `tmp-table-size` and `max-heap-table-size`. They may be too small for this query, forcing your server to put part of it's working set for the query on disk. Also, the key-buffer-size setting is laughably small.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're matching on both `symbol` and `date` you need to set up an index on both those columns, `(symbol, date)`, in order for it to be effective under the conditions you're expressing.

MySQL generally picks the best index for the job for a given table and can't combine two in any meaningful way.

If you have both of these as your primary key, that's very odd and probably damaging to performance. A `UNIQUE` index is better with a regular `INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` ID type column. MySQL's performance is best when the primary key is as compact as possible.

Comment: Doesn't setting ```symbol``` and ```date``` as the primary key already give you that index?

Comment: @PressingOnAlways No, because they are in the wrong order. The current primary key indexes on date first and symbol second. It's not the same thing as indexing by symbol first and date second.

Comment: Thanks.   just created a new index `CREATE INDEX EODDateSym ON endOfDayData (symbol, date) USING BTREE;`
and when I ran it again, still at 17.75 sec.   I will try creating a int auto_incrment and report back.   Thanks again for the quick responses from everyone

Comment: @user3546638 Don't create yet another index. The new index on (Symbol,date) will completely supersede the existing EOD_Symbol index. You don't need or want both.

Answer (score 1):

The third index in your list (`EOD_Date`) is pretty much worthless. You should just drop it. Really. `Date` is already the first field in your primary key, and so the primary key is almost always (if not always) going to be chosen over that index. Keeping that index is actually making your system slower, because MySql will still do the work to maintain that index.

What you need is to update your `EOD_Symbol` index so that it also includes the date field as the second column in the index. You may also want the `close` field as a third column in the index. This will mean that this index covers your primary key, and with the `close` field it also completely covers the correlated sub query (the inner select statement):

```
CREATE INDEX EOD_DateSymClose ON endOfDayData (symbol, date, close) USING BTREE;
```

Make sure this index replaces your existing EOD_Symbol index. Once this index is ready, it would be rare for MySql to want to use that index instead of this one, and it does take real work for MySql to maintain both indexes, especially at insert and update time.

You can get even better performance for this query by using the `symbol, date` order for your primary key, but this is likely to adversely effect other queries, or worse, your insert performance.

Finally, I often see people look at a query that uses a column, and think that they can speed up the query by just adding an index for that specific column. That's *not* how indexes work. An index on a column helps when it fits the order in which a query needs to access the fields. Here, your correlated sub query first needs to restrict the records by symbol, and then within the symbol restrict which records it uses by date, and so you want a query that uses those two columns and in that order.

---

I just saw the edit with the MySql configuration. I'd try increasing your `tmp-table-size` and `max-heap-table-size`. These aren't just for temporary tables, but also where the working sets for running queries live. If they are too small, MySql will have to put data for active queries on disk.

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine that the query plan is a range scan by date and then matching by symbol. The range to scan is pretty large, and it's done per symbol of the outer select.

I'd try to create an index with `(symbol, date)` as columns. Since there are probably far fewer symbols than dates, the range scan by symbol and then filtering by date might be faster, and even maybe done during a hash join between outer and inner queries.

But you have to actually run `explain` a lot, and possibly `analyze table` before proceeding with anything.